# I also did vs Me too

Tags: phrases

***I thought it was hard at school.***

If my response on such phrase is:

> **I also did.**

or

> **Me too.**

Does it mean the same and it doesn't contain any difference? Which response is more popular in this context?

Comment: _I also did_ is not idiomatic; the usual response would be _So did I. Me too_  is more informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it was hard at school.

The usual ways to agree include:

- Me too.
- I did, too.
- So did I.

All of these are perfectly fine in everyday conversation, although "Me too" is more colloquial and "So did I" slightly more formal.

Other variations (specific to the first person's statement that you're replying to) include "I thought so, too" and "I thought so as well" (though I think "as well" is rarely used in the US).

"I also did" and "I did, also" are grammatically correct, but less common.  "I also did" sounds slightly awkward (even though "I also" sounds fine as part of a longer sentence).